# Solr edismax Query Parser parsed query wrong

Tags: solr, solr6

i have strange behavior with edismax Query Parser if add "bq" parameter:

query example:

```
<str name="q">Kindersitz</str>
<str name="defType">edismax</str>
<str name="df">text_de</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
<str name="debugQuery">on</str>
<str name="_">1473154542094</str>
```

parsed  query look OK:

```
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+(text_de:kindersitz)</str>
```

if add "bq" parameter:

```
  <str name="bq">category_1_des^100</str>
```

resulting parsed query NOK:

```
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+(text_de:kindersitz) (text_de:category text_de:1 text_de:des)^100.0</str>
```

why is it searching for text_de:category

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Boost matches in category_1_des? The `bq` field is a query, meaning that it now searches the default field for the value "category_1_des". What is the content of `category_1_des` and what do you want to do? If you want to boost if the `category_1_des` field contain `kindersitz`, try `category_1_des:kindersitz^100`.